# How to write out a boolean equation with 3 variables and two variables per minterm in sigma notation

Tags: digital-logic, boolean-algebra

I would like to know how to represent a boolean equation with three variables and each minterm containing only two variables such as:

```
Y=AB+A'C+BC
```

into sigma notation. I know that if each of the minterms has three variables then I can construct a table to read off the sigma notation easily enough. For example, with three variables A,B and C in an equation I would construct a table as follows:

```
A B C    MINTERM    m#
0 0 0    A'B'C'     m0
0 0 1    A'B'C      m1
0 1 0    A'BC'      m2
0 1 1    A'BC       m3
1 0 0    AB'C'      m4
1 0 1    AB'C       m5
1 1 0    ABC'       m6
1 1 1    ABC        m7
```

To construct the sigma notation, I would simply read off the minterms matching them against the terms in my equation and order them by their binary value. But, if the equation has three variables and only two variables (or even one variable) exist in each minterm then I can't do the translation. How is it done?

This is not a homework assignment and any help would be appreciated.

Comment: AB = ABC' + ABC. Does that help?

Comment: you can also use the table in your question .... first circle all `AB` ... then all `A'C` ... then all `BC`

Answer (score 1):

This might help you:

$$ AB + \bar{A}C + BC = $$
$$ = AB(C + \bar{C}) + \bar{A}(B + \bar{B})C + (A + \bar{A})BC $$
$$ = ABC + AB\bar{C} + \bar{A}BC + \bar{A}\bar{B}C + ABC + \bar{A}BC $$
$$ = \bar{A}\bar{B}C + \bar{A}BC + AB\bar{C} + ABC $$
$$ = \Sigma{m(1, 3, 6, 7)} $$